# Use multiple targets for $(document).on()

Tags: jquery-ui, audio, controls

I was wondering if you guys can help me with something.

i have the following code set:

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter','input',function(){
 soundHover.play();
 });
 $(document).on('mouseleave','input',function(){
 soundHover.pause();
 soundHover.currentTime = 0;
 });
```

I also have a Jquery UI controlGroup formed from different controls.
I would want to use 1 function for all different controls something like instead of 'input' use 'input label select'. I works for each separately, but when i use them together, it does not work.

Is it possible to refer to multiple controls in a control group? if yes, how can I do it?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong delimiter, if i use "," between the control it works as intended.

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter','input,label,a',function(){
 soundHover.play();
 });
 $(document).on('mouseleave','input,label,a',function(){
 soundHover.pause();
 soundHover.currentTime = 0;
 });
```

I still have not gotten the 'select' part to work though.

Comment: just an extra tip, you can write it up like this also

`$(document).on('mouseenter','input,label,a',function(){
   console.log("play");
 }).on('mouseleave','input,label,a',function(){
   console.log("pause");
 });`

I checked in jsfiddle and the events are getting fired